# D3.js geographic data visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js is this possible to draw many circles in each country portion of the map? As this is possible to draw one circle in each portion of the country of the map using this code...

```
selectAll("circle") 
.data(data.features) 
.enter() 
.append("circle") 
.attr("cx", d.lon) 
.attr("cy", d.lat)
```

How can I code to draw multiple circles in each portion of the map, like in Pakistan area there should be four to five circles... ?